Shir Hamalot Before Yishtabach in Hoshana Raba
Some Kehilot say in Hoshana Raba Mizmor Shir Hamaalot after Yishtabach as in Yamim Noraim (ספר ברית כהונה (ג'רבא) ומנהגי קאמרנא ובלוח בעלז (דבר יום ביומו) ), whereas other Kehilot it is written no to say it (בספר עמק ברכה בסידור צלותא דאברהם ובספר דרכי חיים ושלום).
What is the reason behind each custom?

For not saying it at anytime: You contradict the Tur by not putting all the psalms between Barukh Sheamar and Yishtabach.
